# Which is more correct: T-shirt or t-shirt?

Tags: orthography, capitalization

Can we use small letter, while writing: T-shirt?
What is correct and why: T-shirt or t-shirt?

Thank you.

Comment: Related question on ELL: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1277/why-should-the-t-in-t-shirt-be-capitalized

Comment: This is a matter of style, but capitalization helps the reader comprehend that the letter is named, not pronounced, as with *A-frame*, *C-clamp*, *J-curve*, *O-ring*, *S-duct*, *U-turn*, or *X-ray*.

Comment: ......... iPad?

Answer (score 5):

***[T-shirt](http://grammarist.com/spelling/t-shirt-tee-shirt/), t-shirt, tee-shirt, tee shirt:***

> - Most dictionaries recommend T-shirt, and it is the form most common in edited writing throughout the English-speaking world. Yet t-shirt is gaining ground, and both tee-shirt and tee shirt have some adherents. ***Not one of them is considered incorrect, so while T-shirt might be the safer choice, the others aren’t wrong.***

The Grammarist

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=T%20shirt%2C%20t%20shirt%2C%20tee%20shirt&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CT%20shirt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ct%20shirt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctee%20shirt%3B%2Cc0) "tee shirt" (with or without hyphen) appears  to be the more common expression.

Comment: You forgot the hyphens in the Ngram search. Adding them puts T-shirt way in the lead, with t-shirt a more common than tee shirt https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=T-shirt%2Ct-shirt%2Ctee+shirt&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CT%20-%20shirt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ct%20-%20shirt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctee%20shirt%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 4):

T-shirt, because the shirt is bilaterally symmetric -- the left side looks just like the right side, but reflected.  A capital T is symmetric in this way, but a small letter t is not (in the usual typefaces).